# expires_in or expires_at used for access tokens in OpenId connect?

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, identityserver4, access-token, openid-connect

I'm confused as to why the OpenId connect specifications (source: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#TokenResponse) refer to an 'expires_in' key in the JWT, while in ASP.NET Core 2, when using IdentityServer4, expires_at is used, but if you wish to manipulate it, you refer to it as "expires_in".
Am I missing something here?

Below is a snippet showing what I'm refering to exactly - tokenResult holds the newly refreshed tokens, by passing in the needed client information + secret (defined in tokenClient), as well as the current refresh token (stored in currentRefreshToken). Why does tokenResult have a property "ExpiresIn", when the one displayed/stored in the access token is named "expires_at"? Shouldn't they both be unified, even though specifications clearly state it should be named "expires_in" (which the property follows, but actual implementation in the JWT doesn't)?

```
var tokenResult = await tokenClient.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(currentRefreshToken)
var expiresAt = DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(tokenResult.ExpiresIn)
updatedTokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken
{
    Name = "expires_at"
    Value = expiresAt.ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
}
```

EDIT: I just realized that 'expires_at' might not refer to the access token, but the whole authentication ticket? Please correct me on this, I'm really confused.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The JWT uses `iat` and `exp` as claim names, I'm not aware of an `expires_at` in the spec.

`expires_in` is a value that comes back in the token response and that refers to the lifetime of the `access_token` returned. I suspect the thinking behind it was to allow scheduling of refresh without having to inspect the `exp` claim in the token.

The topic you linked to (https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#TokenResponse) shows the token endpoint response and not the contents of the JWT.

Where are you seeing `expires_at` surfaced? `AuthenticationToken` is I think an ASP.Net Identity thing so it may well be a calculated value that library stores and is nothing to do with `identityserver4` or OpenID Connect at all.

Based on your comment, it’ll be the OIDC middleware adding those properties to the sign in scheme. Check out the code here on line 138:

https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/7e14b052ea9cb935ec4f5cb0485b4edb5d41297a/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth/OAuthHandler.cs

So basically it’s an implementation detail specific to ASP.Net Core’s implementation of OIDC and not part of the protocol itself.

Comment: Before I do any of this, when I do the following
`var expires_at = await currentContext.GetTokenAsync("expires_at");`

It seemingly returns expires_at, even though I've no idea where it exists, and what it correlates to. I understand what I'm calling when I do 
`await currentContext.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.ExpiresIn);`
but this is something different. I thought it's custom-made, but no exception is thrown when a new user passes through that code, and indeed it returns an actual DateTime string?

Comment: Expanded my answer based on your comment.